# UICollectionViewCell NSindexpath reference position

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uistoryboard, uicollectionviewcell, nsindexpath

How do I reference a specific `UICollectionViewCell` so that each of them segue to different VCs?

**Here is the code for the cells:**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Cell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MY_CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.myCellImages[0]];
    UIImage *cellImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.myCellImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
    return cell;
}
```

So this displays a bunch of different cells depending on how many images I load in to my array.

**say my array is:**

```
 self.myCellImages = @[@"1.jpg", @"2.jpg",.... @"20.jpg"];
```

how do I reference an individual cell so that it segues into different VC? For example, clicking on the cell that has image 1.jpg `segues` into 1VC and clicking on the cell with17.jpg segues to 17VC

**Is it something like:**

```
if (NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];)
{
//segue here
}
```

I can't figure out the correct syntax

Thanks to Timothy, I added

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath
{
    NSString *storyboardId = @"main_to_VC1"; 
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:storyboardId sender:indexPath];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to establish segues between your collection view controller (not the cell) and the destination controllers, giving each a unique storyboard ID.

Then in the `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` delegate method, decide which controller you want to segue to based on the `indexPath` and initiate the segue programmatically:

```
- (void)collectionView:collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath
{
    NSString *storyboardId = ...; // determine storyboard ID based on indexPath
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:storyboardId sender:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: Hi Timothy, thank you for your help. I created two segues and named one main_to_VC1 and another main_to_VC2, from the collectionVC not the cell and set them to "push." Then, I added the collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath as noted in my edit uptop. However it's switching the view to a blank view when main_to_VC1/2 have individual content. Do I need to do something with the cells aswell?

Comment: Ah! I fixed it. Had to do: (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView

However, when I press the back button on the new VC to go back to the main collection view, I have to press it twice in order for it to go back. Any ideas why it might be doing this?

Comment: Hm my bad... I was confused by my own code for a second. So, it works in that it segues but I'm still confused as to how to make it so that each individual cell segues to a different VC. Since this cell is reuseable, it creates 20 (if I have 20 items in my array..) cells when it runs. How do I get each of those to have their own VC to segue to?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to do. Do you literally have multiple child controllers defined in your storyboard or do you have one child view controller that you need to configure with data specific to the selected cell?

Comment: moose I actually figured out my issue, I wasn't giving them correct identifiers... thank you for the help!